# How to validate a redux-form field using an api asynchronously

Tags: validation, reactjs, asynchronous, redux-form, axios

I am new to React and can not understand how to call an external api (possibly using axios/promises) and validate a redux-form field asynchronously. Eg checking weather an email is already taken. If someone can show me an example, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `SubmissionError`,
more details on documentation [redux-form doc](http://redux-form.com/6.7.0/docs/api/SubmissionError.md/)